# Typescript avoid exporting types with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am learning Typescript and I am struggling with generics.

I have created a simple function that prints the keys/values of a given object in a particular order. An additional label property can be provided to print an alternative to the key string.

```
// object-printer.ts
interface Spec<T> {
  key: keyof T;
  label?: string;
}

export default function objectPrinter<T>(ob: T, printSpec: Spec<T>[]): void {
  printSpec.forEach((spec) => {
    let label = spec.label || spec.key;
    console.log(`${label}: ${ob[spec.key]}`);
  });
}
```

I then import the function and use it

```
import objectPrinter from "./object-printer";

interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
}

const user: User = {
  firstName: "Wurzel",
  lastName: "Gummage",
  age: 100,
};

const printSpec = [
  { key: "age", label: "Trips Around Sun" },
  { key: "lastName" },
];

objectPrinter(user, printSpec); // Typescript complains about type of printSpec
// Trips Around Sun: 100
// lastName: Gummage
```

Typescript give me an error:

> Argument of type '({ key: string; label: string; } | { key: string;
> label?: undefined; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Spec[]'.   Type '{ key: string; label: string; } | { key:
> string; label?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Spec'.
> Type '{ key: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Spec'.
> Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof User'.

To fix this I can also export `interface Spec` and specify the type for `printSpec`;

Is there a better way to infer the type using generics or is it necessary to export the type Spec?

Comment: Seems like TypeScript decides on the type of `printSpec` (containing `string`, not `keyof` anything) and won't change its mind later, but interestingly it works if you inline the value of `printSpec` in the call to `objectPrinter`.  Makes sense since TypeScript can validate it all at once that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens because Typescript assigns a type to your `printSpec` variable which uses `string` to describe the values `"age"` and `"lastName"`.  `string` is too broad as we no longer know that these values are valid keys of the `User` interface.

#### Solution #1: No Intermediate Variable

You won't have any errors if you avoid the intermediate variable `printSpec` since no type widening occurs.  You can pass your spec directly to the `objectPrinter` function:

```
objectPrinter(user, [
  { key: "age", label: "Trips Around Sun" },
  { key: "lastName" },
]);
```

#### Solution #2: `as const`

Typescript has a special `as const` assertion that causes it to see a variable as an immutable constant and read all strings as their literal values.

If we declare the whole `printSpec` variable `as const` then we have to deal with `readonly` issues in the types.  But we can add `as const` to the key strings.

```
const printSpec = [
  { key: "age" as const, label: "Trips Around Sun" },
  { key: "lastName" as const},
];

objectPrinter(user, printSpec);
```

#### Solution #3: Assign `Spec` Type

> To fix this I can also export `interface Spec` and specify the type for `printSpec`

What you are suggesting will definitely work.  You obviously already know this but I am including it here for completeness.

```
const printSpec: Spec<User>[] = [
  { key: "age", label: "Trips Around Sun" },
  { key: "lastName" },
];

objectPrinter(user, printSpec);
```

Comment: One refinement to solution 2, if you change `objectPrinter` to have a read-only parameter, i.e. `printSpec: readonly Spec<T>[]`, then you can mark the **entire** `printSpec` object `as const`, to avoid marking every `key` as such.

Comment: @user2740650 You're right.  I assumed that there would be other nested properties further down in the `Spec` that needed to be made `readonly` but I didn't actually check.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive answer, the typescript error is much clearer now